# Debug Maven to find out the war file name that has been created

Tags: maven-2

I am getting this exception in Maven2 when i run mvn deploy

Please see the error

```
[INFO] An Ant BuildException has occured: Warning: Could not find file D:\bayer\service\target\${file.name}.war to copy.
I have this below line under my POM.xml file
```

Please tell me is it possible to see the file.name that is forming at runtime ??

I have this line under my POM.xml file

```
<copy file="${project.build.directory}/${file.name}.${project.packaging}" tofile="${deploy.home}/${webapps.dir}/${file.name}.${project.packaging}" />
```

How can we debug this ??

Comment: I tried this way :  <echo>The version is kiran ${file.name}</echo>  and the output being formed is * [echo] The version is kiran ${file.name} *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default maven generated wars will have the following name:

```
${artifactId}-${version}.war
```

In you antrun plugin you can reference maven properties ( see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html ).

So if you replace file.name property by a direct maven reference it will just work:

```
${project.build.directory}/${artifactId}-${version}.${project.packaging}
```

( above assumes that your ant script is inside the pom.xml and not externalized )

You also can override that in the build section of your pom.xml:

```
<build>
   <finalName>MySuperCoolApplication</finalName>
   ...
</build>
```

For general debug output from mvn just use the -X flag